# JOIN vs "just" SELECT

Tags: mysql, date, select, join

I have the next tables:

```
date         Income    AccIncome     
--------------------------------    
2016-10-1     10          10         
2017-11-1     20          30    


date         Qty       AccQty     
--------------------------------    
2016-10-1     2          2         
2017-11-1     4          6            


date         Ava       AccAva
--------------------------------    
2016-10-1     3          3         
2017-11-1     4          7
```

I need to obtain:

```
date       Income AccIncome  Qty   AccQty  Ava  AccAva
------------------------------------------------------
2016-10-1   10      10        2     2       3     3     
2017-11-1   20      30        4     6       4     7
```

I could use a select using all these tables but how could this be done with a JOIN? Could the JOIN be much faster than using just a SELECT over all these tables picking up just the fields I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner join   on date  if the  joining  values in rows always match

```
  select a.date, a.income, a.AccIncome, b.Qty, b.AccQty, c.Ava, c.AccAva
  from table1 a
  inner join table2 b on a.date= b.date 
  inner join table3 c on a.date = c.date
```

or left join if can not match

```
  select a.date, a.income, a.AccIncome, b.Qty, b.AccQty, c.Ava, c.AccAva
  from table1 a
  left join table2 b on a.date= b.date 
  left join table3 c on a.date = c.date
```

if you use only a select withou join and on condtion you obtain a cartesia product of all the rows .. so in your case  instead of two row  as result  .. you get  8 rows

and the inner/left join is normally much more faster that a cross join ( a select over all table)  because work on reduced set o rows.. for help the join performance is useful a proper indexinig of the rows

the on clause in join and the same condition in where clause do the same work .. is only a diffrent sintax in the first case  you have an explict  join sintax more clear to read  in the secondo you have an inplicit join .

Comment: How this JOIN could be much faster than using something like:
SELECT a.date, a.income, a.AccIncome, b.Qty, b.AccQty, c.Ava, c.AccAva
FROM A, B, C
where A.DATE = B.date AND B.date=C.date  ?

Comment: yes  .. is normally much faster .. .. and you can add index for better  performance in join ... answer updated ..

Comment: the where condition and on condition do the same work